# How to include CocoaPods in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vk, vk-sdk

I try to use the VKontakte framework in my Delphi App. However, I have no idea how from Delphi I can play with a pod. The doc of VKontakte just say (https://vk.com/dev/ios_sdk):

```
Podfile
pod "VK-ios-sdk"
```

How I can include this in my Delphi project? where I can find the framework binary file?

Comment: As I understand it, pods are like packages of source - they're compiled when you build the project that uses them. Building a framework from source in Xcode is pretty straightforward anyway, so you would: clone the repo, load the project into Xcode, select the root in Project Navigator, select the VKSdkFramework target in the Targets list, then in the menu click Product|Build, then once it is done, select VKSdkFramework.framework under Products in the Project Navigator, and the full path to it will appear in the File Inspector window on the right

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use that SDK with Delphi.

Comment: @Olivier why ?  what david say to do will not work ?

Comment: You can compile the library with Xcode indeed, but then how will you use it from Delphi?

Comment: @Olivier We can use compiled framework in delphi it's work pretty well

Comment: @DaveNottage thanks ! perfect it's work, i think it's deserve to be an answer for people using delphi but that don't know very well x-code and will meet the same problem! only one think that worry me a little, the path is Users/loki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VK-ios-sdk-ccvvxpixcnbsenbofrzlkvhdwgzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VKSdkFramework.framework and it's contain Debug-iphonesimulator and i m a little worry to see "debug", I want the library to be compiled for release. Also the library seam to be signed, does this will not cause some trouble ?

Comment: @DaveNottage Also I see that under VKSdkFramework.framework I have ru.lproj and en.lproj, do I need to include them also in delphi ? and how ?

Comment: Hi @DaveNottage.  It'd be a good idea I think if you post your first comment as an answer.

Comment: @DaveNottage yes it's must be an answer. in the answer you can also gave the command line: xcodebuild -project VK-ios-sdk.xcodeproj -target VKSdkFramework -configuration Release CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=. clean build in this way not even need to launch Xcode :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, pods are packages of source. To compile the framework:

1. Clone the repo Load the project into Xcode
2. Select the root of the project in Project Navigator
3. Select the VKSdkFramework target in the Targets list
4. In the Xcode menu click Product|Build
5. Select VKSdkFramework.framework under Products in the Project
   Navigator, and the full path to it will appear in the File Inspector
   window on the right